# Play activator debug gets terminated on trying to remote debug from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am new to play framework. I have an existing play application. I am supposed to understand it and make enhancements. So I am running the application on my windows 7 machine. It runs fine. On using debug(activator -jvm-debug), the jvm  starts listening on default port 9999. Till this point everything is fine. When I start debugging it as a remote java application from my eclipse, the process listening on the port 9999 gets terminated. I have been monitoring the activity on Windows Resource Monitor. I have no clue where to check for the issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: if you have no clue with the sources and code and logs and traces, how should we have one without them?

Comment: I am sorry sir. I don't mean to ask what the issue is exactly. I just wanted some help that if you find yourself in this situation, what would you do next or if you got such issue in the past and fixed it, what was the fix.

Comment: @Ravuri spoorthy can you be more specific with the errors that you get, may be you can look into logs and traces.

Comment: The common things that you can check for a generic situation like **Message: “Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection Refused”** 
1) Have you setup the remote VM to accept connections?
'
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=10000,suspend=n yourServer'

2) Is there a firewall in the way?

Are you specifying the correct host / port?

Answer (score 1):

The common things that you can check for a generic situation like

> Message: “Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection Refused”

1) Have you setup the remote VM to accept connections?

```
 java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=10000,suspend‌​=n yourServer
```

2) Is there a firewall in the way? Are you specifying the correct host / port?